# Getting data into view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi I'm a newbie to Laravel. I've been trying to add a country dropdown to a registration form.
I followed this https://github.com/Monarobase/country-list

Installed the package and added the config in app.php (under 'providers' and 'aliases')

Added route in web.php

```
Route::get('/countries', function () {
return Countries::getList('en', 'html');
});
```

Created countries.blade.php and added this to test

```
@foreach($Countries as $country)
<li>$country</li>
@endforeach
```

All works fine and gives me this output, which is what I want

[image]

I want to add this to my register page (register.blade.php), when add it like this it gives me an error "$Countries is undefined". **My question is, how I do get that drop down to register view and where do I define this variable?**

```
<select name="country" class="form-control" style="width:250px; border-color:#eee">
   <option value="old('country')">--- Select Country ---</option>
       @foreach($Countries as $country)
         <li>$country</li>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `return Countries::get()` is not the right approach here; you need to return your view, and include the variable, like `return view('countries')->with(['countries' => Countries::getList('en', 'php')]);`. Read the documentation for all of this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views, and the Package: https://github.com/Monarobase/country-list#usage

Answer (score 0):

Is just a blade syntax missing

instead of this:

```
<li>$country</li>
```

Do this (with brackets):

```
<li>{{ $country }}</li>
```

Comment: There's more than that: `old('country')` is missing the blade brackets. And `<li>` inside a `<select>` element is invalid, those should be `<option> elements

Comment: Yes! I dont see this before.

Answer (score 0):

**First**
In your `RegisterController` find the method which returns the `register.blade.php` view and add this line:

```
$country = Countries::getList('en', 'html');
```

**Second**
In the last line of that same method, add this `$country` variable after the view name like this:

```
return view('register.blade.php',$country);
```

docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#nested-view-directories

Note: I am just guessing the register blade name. Do change accordingly if not same

Comment: Hi Psycho, that didn't work. I should probably mention that I'm using JetStream's registration component, I don't have a RegisterController in the http/controllers folder, I think it's handled from elsewhere according to the documentation here: https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/registration.html#customizing-the-registration-view still puzzled. :(

Comment: @OmniGrind as a newbie, you shouldn't have gone for jetstream. First learn the basics of Larabel, i would suggest